# She came in in a wheelchair

Tags: grammar

She came in in a wheelchair. Do I need a comma between the two repeated words?

Comment: While you don't need a comma, your ear told you there is a problem with "in in" as is. The common fix is to change one. If "in a wheelchair" is hard to change, change "came in" to entered or such.

Comment: In speech it sounds fine but in writing it's a little awkward. Yosef's comment is a good start.